# Are file names actually pointers to their respective data stored?

Tags: linux, macos, window, binary-tree

I'm pretty new to Data Structure and File system. I'm trying to understand the file name system in computer. Are all file names pointers to their respective data?

For eg, if my computer, I have

- myfile1
- myfile2

In any point in time, I can change my file name and it becomes,

- myfile_changed
- myfile2

But their respective data don't change. So I wonder it's because of filesystems (Binary Tree?) or anything else?

This would sound like a pretty noobie. But any suggestion to a better explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might suggest reading the following links which explain the concepts of [files](http://www.linfo.org/file.html), [filesystems](http://www.linfo.org/filesystem.html), and [inodes](http://www.linfo.org/inode.html).

To quickly summarize however, your intuition is correct that a filename is not directly linked to a file's data. A filename is associated with an *inode*, a data structure which contains metadata information about the file and points to where the file's the data can be found on disk. Renaming a file simply changes the name associated with the file's inode; the inode itself does not change and still points to the same data on disk.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look.